# Updating Visual FoxPro from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to update some simple Visual FoxPro tables with SQL Server. I've created a linked server with the following:

```
sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'UTIL',
@srvproduct = 'VFP',
@provider = 'VFPOLEDB',
@datasrc = 'L:\M2MDATA\Util\util.dbc'
GO
```

And the following works:

```
select * from UTIL...utcomp
```

However, I cannot use the following statement:

```
update util...utcomp
set fmaddress = '123 Elvis Dr.'
where fcsqldb = 'M2MDATA01'
```

I receive the error:

> OLE DB provider "VFPOLEDB" for linked server "util" returned message Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each
>   OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
>   Msg 7333, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Cannot fetch a row using a bookmark from OLE DB provider "VFPOLEDB" for linked server "util".

I have the latest version (9.0) installed so I should have the latest provider. Am I doing something wrong? Is it not possible to update VFP from SQL?

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples on the [Fox Wiki](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VisualFoxProDataFromSQLServer~VFP) that might help. Specifically the last one which shows how to access VFP data through OLEDB without using a linked server.

Comment: Great stuff, particularly note the change in provider string for SQL 2008, AllowInProcess setting and also check permissions on the folder as they will require the *user* account to have permissions as opposed to the sqlserver identity.